# Proving $[\mathbb{Q}(m(\alpha)):\mathbb{Q}]\leq[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, riemann-surfaces, minimal-polynomials, transcendence-degree

Suppose $m$ is the minimal polynomial of a set $S$ of complex numbers such that for a complex number $\alpha\not\in S$, $\alpha$ is a root of the derivative of $m$. I want to prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(m(\alpha)):\mathbb{Q}]\leq[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$. I have tried some examples and my intuition tells me it has something to do with linear combinations of $\alpha$ being already in the extension, but I don't really know how to prove it. Any help or hint will be welcome. Thank you very much!

PS: This is in the context of Riemann surfaces, but I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: Hint: $m(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$, so $m(\alpha)\in\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. In other words, your intuition is not wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to define an injective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(m(\alpha))$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. But I'm not sure how to do it. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Oh, you want to do it that way. Prove that
$$\phi: f(x)\mapsto f(m(\alpha))$$ defines a ring homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb{Q}[x]\to\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Then show that the minimal polynomial of $m(\alpha)$ generates the kernel. Then apply the first isomorphism theorem.